# Beamer - Using nested itemize have different "top point" in frame, than frame with no nested itemize

Tags: beamer

having great difficulties "writing" the problem, but I have a very simple example showing the issue.

When having one frame in which I use itemize, and then skip to another frame, where I use a nested itemize. The "top point" moves, resulting in a presentation that looks, in my opinion, awful.

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item test
        \end{itemize}
    \end{frame}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item test
            \begin{itemize}
                \item 11
            \end{itemize}
        \end{itemize}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

And this results in:

### [image]

Is there any way to ensure the content to grow downwards from a fixed top point?

Comment: There is not much to fix here, in beamer the contents is vertically centered and have different heights, it is not added from the top as in PowerPoint. Perhaps you should be more specific about what it is you want to achieve?

Comment: Edited the question.

I want the content to have a "fixed" top; in other words, for the content to "grow" downward

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an empty line before the inner itemize:

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item test
        \end{itemize}
    \end{frame}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item test

            \begin{itemize}
                \item 11
            \end{itemize}
        \end{itemize}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

(This is imho a bug in the beamer itemize implementation. See also https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/306.)

Comment: This worked. Much appreciated